# Display multiple objects in property grid

Tags: c#, winforms

```
Array selected = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(Object), (this.designer1.DesignerHost.GetService(typeof(ISelectionService)) as ISelectionService).SelectionCount);
(this.designer1.DesignerHost.GetService(typeof(ISelectionService)) as ISelectionService).GetSelectedComponents().CopyTo(selected, 0);
_PropertyGrid.SelectedObjects = new object[] {selected};
```

I am trying to display multiple objects in the PropertyGrid, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: It does not display the properties, it displays the array it self. I converted the code from VB.NET. in VB its working but somewhere in the C# is moething wrong. In VB.NET I was just able to do .SelectedObjects = selected but in C# it gives a compiler error, so I had to change to .SelectedObjects = new object[] {selected}. it compiles but does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer myself :)

```
_PropertyGrid.SelectedObjects = (selected as object[]);
```

does the job ;)